# Android app regression caused by CPU busy

Tags: android, cpu, cpu-usage

I just refactor a module of my APP, but it got a regression due to CPU is busy than before. 
Do you know which will cause the CPU busy? Or how to find the reason of CPU busy?

Comment: What did you refactor for it ?

Comment: @kimkevin I use the MVP(Model-View-Presenter) to refactor it. I copy the same functions and features from old version to new module. And I didn't add any new functions or features.

Comment: hmm .. did you watch Android Profiler too?

Comment: The Profiler doesn't show the difference, and I've watched the systrace, it shows new version is busy than before, but it doesn't show which part  cause this.